# rigidbody's addforce() function doesn't seem to work properly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a simple 3d character controller, but the jump doesn't work at all. I want to use rigidbody in my jump but the .addforce does not work. I have a `Debug.log` to see if it passes the jump condition and it does. The problem is with the `rb.addforce()`. I added the full code below:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
[SerializeField] Transform camera;
[SerializeField] float sens = 3.5f;
[SerializeField] float walkSpeed = 6.0f;
[SerializeField] [Range(0.0f, 0.5f)] float smooth = 0.3f;
[SerializeField] [Range(0.0f, 0.5f)] float smoothMouse = 0.3f;
[SerializeField] float gravity = -13.0f;
[SerializeField] float slopeForce = 6;
[SerializeField] float slopeForceRayLenght = 1.5f;
[SerializeField] float runSpeed = 10;
[SerializeField] float runBuildUp = 4;
[SerializeField] float jumpForce = 10;
[SerializeField] KeyCode jumpk;
[SerializeField] KeyCode runk;

[SerializeField] bool cursorLock = true;

public Rigidbody rb;
public Transform groundCheck;
public float groundDistance = 0.4f;
public LayerMask grndMask;

public bool isGrounded;

float cameraPitch = 0.0f;
float velocityY = 0.0f;
float speed;

Vector2 currentDir = Vector2.zero;
Vector2 currentDirVelocity = Vector2.zero;

Vector2 currentMouseDelta = Vector2.zero;
Vector2 currentMouseDeltaVelocity = Vector2.zero;

CharacterController controller;

void Start()
{
    speed = walkSpeed;

    controller = GetComponent < CharacterController>();
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    if ( cursorLock ) {
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
        Cursor.visible = false;
    }
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    UpdateMouseLook();
    UpdateMovement();
    Jump();
}

void UpdateMouseLook () {
    Vector2 mouseDelta = new Vector2(Input.GetAxis("Mouse X"),         
Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y"));

    currentMouseDelta = Vector2.SmoothDamp(currentMouseDelta, mouseDelta,     
ref currentMouseDeltaVelocity, smoothMouse);

    cameraPitch -= currentMouseDelta.y * sens;

    cameraPitch = Mathf.Clamp(cameraPitch, -90.0f, 90.0f);
    camera.localEulerAngles = Vector3.right * cameraPitch;

    transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * currentMouseDelta.x * sens);
}

void SetSpeed () {
    if ( Input.GetKey(runk) ) {
        speed = Mathf.Lerp(speed, runSpeed, Time.deltaTime * runBuildUp);
    }else {
        speed = Mathf.Lerp(speed, walkSpeed, Time.deltaTime * runBuildUp);
    }
}

void Jump () {
    isGrounded = Physics.CheckSphere(groundCheck.position, groundDistance, 
grndMask);
    if ( isGrounded && Input.GetKeyDown(jumpk)) {
        Debug.Log("jumping");
        rb.AddForce(Vector3.up * jumpForce, ForceMode.Impulse);
    }
}

public bool OnSlope () {
    RaycastHit hit;

    if ( Physics.Raycast(transform.position, Vector3.down, out hit, 
controller.height / 2 * slopeForceRayLenght) ) {
        if ( hit.normal != Vector3.up ) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

void UpdateMovement () {
    Vector2 inputDir = new Vector2(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), 
 Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical"));
    inputDir.Normalize();

    currentDir = Vector2.SmoothDamp(currentDir, inputDir, ref 
 currentDirVelocity, smooth);

    if ( controller.isGrounded ) {
        velocityY = 0.0f;
    }
    velocityY += gravity * Time.deltaTime;

    Vector3 velocity = (transform.forward * currentDir.y + transform.right 
* currentDir.x) * speed + Vector3.up * velocityY;

    controller.Move(velocity * Time.deltaTime);

    if((inputDir.x != 0 || inputDir.y != 0) && OnSlope() ) {
        controller.Move(Vector3.down * controller.height / 2 * slopeForce 
 * Time.deltaTime);
    }
    SetSpeed();
  }
}
```

I made sure that the `is kinematic` box is unchecked and in the rigidbody tab, the mass is set to 1, drag to 1 and angular drag to 0.05. Also the `Use gravity` box is checked and the `jumpk` key is set to the space bar (I set it in the unity editor). Didn't touch the other options. For the player I use an empty object.

Comment: Have you tried increasing the jumpForce to a higher number than 10f?

Comment: Hi! yes, all the way up to 1000 and nothing works

Comment: Totally unrelated but may I ask what you expect from the line `rb.AddForce(0, 0, jumpForce, ForceMode.Impulse);` ? ^^ And, **yes**, please post the rest of your movement related code ...maybe you are somewhere overruling the velocity change caused by the jump ...

Comment: oh, i used that to check if the addforce is working (in this case pushing me a bit when the game starts) and it doesn't. Also, I edited the initial question and added the full code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be because it is kind of awkward to use character controller and rigid body. For the jump part use this:

```
void Jump()
{
    // your ground check code works. Keep it.
    velocityY = Mathf.Sqrt(jumpForce * 2f * gravity);
    controller.Move(0f, velocityY * Time.deltaTime, 0f)
}
```

Comment: it doesn't let me use multiple plarameters for the `Move()`. And if type only `velocityY * Time.deltaTime` it doesn't work because `velocityY` is a float.

Comment: try this: void Jump()
{
    // your ground check code works. Keep it.
    velocityY = Mathf.Sqrt(jumpForce * 2f * gravity);
    controller.Move(Vector3.up * velocityY * Time.deltaTime);